# Weather Underground 3-day forecast JSON response returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, weather

I've been developing a weather app and am having trouble returning the 3-day forecast data object. It keeps returning undefined after my parse.

I've gotten as far as learning that it's returning an array but I'm still hung up on accessing the objects in that array.

All my other calls are working fine, it's in this snippet that I'm having troubles:

```
var forecast = parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'];

for (index in forecast) {
    console.log('Weather forecast for ' + forecast[index]['title'] +
        ' is ' + forecast[index]['fcttext_metric']);
}
```

Official docs: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs

Comment: don't use `for ... in` on an array - try `console.log(index)` in the `for ... in` loop to see why (you most likely wont see anything wrong, but if you do, you'll have an answer to your problem)

Comment: Is it returning `undefined` or an Array?

Comment: also, it's preferable to use to use `var forecast = parsed_json.forecast.txt_forecast.forecastday;` and `forecast[index].title` etc - though this has nothing to do with your issue

Comment: It's returning undefiied, not ant array. @blurd

Comment: When I log just the index It returns this error still : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'txt_forecast' of undefined @JaromandaX

Comment: is `forecast` undefined? is `parsed_json` undefined?

Comment: Look in the network tab to see what is actually being received.  Provide that.  It might also help to check how you're parsing the JSON.

Comment: oh, so the data is not what you expect **before** the loop - my bad

Comment: I could be wrong but I think my attempt to parse forecast is returning undefined and not allowing the parse to move past onto txt_forecast and then to forecastday @azium

Comment: Well it's not hard to check. before any of the code you posted `console.log(parsed_json)`. what is the result of that?

Comment: Okay, so it looks like the 'forecast' parse is not passing into the JSON - I'm only receiving 'current observation' and 'location' in my response (which are the other two properties I'm requesting).

Comment: `'current observation' and 'location'` are not part of the response for a forecast API call according to the API docs - looks like you aren't requesting a forecast at all - can you show the request you are making?

Comment: Here's what I'm working with: https://jsfiddle.net/bsmith64/26LdLdcy/ Ignore the code below the ajax call, it's irrelevant. @JaromandaX

Comment: Log the result to the console so you can inspect it. https://jsfiddle.net/reergymerej/26LdLdcy/1/  I doubt anyone can help you parse data unless you post it here.

Comment: Object {response: Object, location: Object, current_observation: Object} I suspected only location and current observation were being returned but does that explain the undefined response? Thanks for walking me through this, first project working with JSON. @blurd

Comment: `but does that explain the undefined response` - yes, there is no `forecast` property in parsed_json (i.e. it's `undefined` ), so the error is when you try to get a property of `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the fiddle you posted](https://jsfiddle.net/bsmith64/26LdLdcy/) your request url does **NOT** include forecast - hence, no forecast is returned

```
url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/.../geolookup/conditions/q/US/" + postCode +".json"
```

what if you used

```
url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/.../geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/US/" + postCode +".json"
```

I tested the above, and it does work

Comment: Yes! You're right, this resolved the 'undefined' response. My response came back: Object {response: Object, location: Object, current_observation: Object, forecast: Object}
weatherScript.js:82 0
weatherScript.js:82 1
weatherScript.js:82 2
weatherScript.js:82 3
weatherScript.js:82 4
weatherScript.js:82 5
weatherScript.js:82 6
weatherScript.js:82 7 Thanks! @jaromandaX